# enable rewrite mode apache2

Tags: apache2

I am trying to rewrite the apache2 config file but seems impossible
i tried to enable it with sudo a2enmod rewrite but i keep getting this error :

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_BE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "fr_FR.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("fr_FR.UTF-8").
Module rewrite already enabled
```

Did anyone know how to fix this issue in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Some of your locale env vars are set to `de_BE.UTF-8`, but you system doesn't have that locale installed. Either install that locale or change your env vars to use one that exists. You can test with by running the `locale` command line utility.

Comment: How can I install the locale ? by running the locale command i see some of my env vars are de_BE.UTF-8 . To what i should change them ? and how ?

Comment: Re "*How can I install the locale ?*", Using your system's package manager. /// Re "*To what i should change them ?*", `locale -a` shows which locales you have installed. /// Re "*and how*", By editing whichever script you used to set them.

Answer (score 2):

Your question shows 2 things:

You're trying to enable rewrite. Your command to enable it results in it saying that the module rewrite is already enabled. Please verify if that is the case.

Your other question might be due to the warning by perl about the locale.

Please edit the file `/etc/locale.gen` (using sudo and your favorite editor) and uncomment all locales that you need on your system. If you live in the German part of Belgium you need to uncomment the proper locales in that file.

After saving that file, execute `sudo locale-gen`.

Please retry your perlscript if after that you still get the above warnings by Perl.